# How to change default install dir in smart device cab project?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, cab

I have created smart device CAB project and its installed successfully in

> \Program Files

by default BUT I want to make default install directory

> \Application

folder instead of

> \Program Files in Windows CE device 6.0

(MC3190 Motorola device).

Do you any idea to set default path or change "%InstallDir% macro value? Please provide help if any which very needful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `[DefaultDestDir]` in the [`\[DestinationDirs\]` section of your INF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms906510.aspx).